# SQL Update goes forever, basic inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have this SQL Update Query which doesn't want to run. It's pretty simple, i want to update T with the values given in the subselect E.
Subselect E returns 3323 rows, and T has the same 3323 rows.

They are uniquely linked by dim01,dim02,dim03 and the time.
(the source of T is the same as E)
Watching the execution plan i see nothing wrong and it looks like it should be performant.

```
        update T
        set     T.ACT04 = E.ACT04,
                T.ACT05 = E.ACT05
        from (  select  left(A.PERIOD_ID,4) + right(A.PERIOD_ID,2) as PERIOD_ID, A.[d_1],A.[d_3],A.[d_5],
                sum(C.[V_AANREKENING]) as ACT04 ,sum(C.[V_VORDERING]) as ACT05
              FROM [CVL].dbo.[C_DS_DB_FI_SOK] A INNER JOIN [CVD].[dbo].[REF_YTD] B
                ON left(A.PERIOD_ID,4) + right(A.PERIOD_ID,2) = B.ref_period
                                                                 INNER JOIN [CVL].[dbo].[C_DS_DB_FI_SOK] C
                ON B.agg_period = left(C.PERIOD_ID,4) + right(C.PERIOD_ID,2) and 
                left(A.PERIOD_ID,4) = left(C.PERIOD_ID,4) and 
                A.d_1 = C.d_1 and 
                A.d_2 = C.d_2 and 
                A.d_3 = C.d_3 and
                A.D_BELEIDSDOMEIN = C.D_BELEIDSDOMEIN and
                A.D_BELEIDSVELD = C.D_BELEIDSVELD and
                A.D_BELEIDSITEM = C.D_BELEIDSITEM and
                A.D_7 = C.D_7
              WHERE LEFT(A.d_7, 1) = 2 or LEFT(A.d_7, 1) = 6 or LEFT(A.d_7, 1) = 7 or LEFT(A.d_7, 2) = 42 or LEFT(A.d_7, 2) = 17 
                    or LEFT(A.d_7, 4) = 4943 or LEFT(A.d_7, 4) = 4944 or LEFT(A.d_7, 4) = 4949 or LEFT(A.d_7, 4) = 4959 or LEFT(A.d_7, 3) = 102
              group by A.PERIOD_ID, A.d_1, A.d_3, A.d_5 ) E
              inner join [CVD].[dbo].[FACT_QUANTITY_TMP] T
              on E.d_1 = T.dim01 and
                 E.d_3 = T.dim02 and
                 E.d_5 = T.dim03 and
                 E.PERIOD_ID = T.YEAR + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, T.FULL_DATE) AS varchar(2)), 2)
```

It would suprise me that inner joining 3323 records with another 3323 records would take more then 15 minutes.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if it were my query I'd look at 1) simplifying the query to use intermediate table variables or temp tables, 2) simplifying the where clauses if possible just to see if that's related to the problem, 3) seeing if there's an index on [C_DS_DB_FI_SOK].D_7,  4) shooting the original programmer or database designer

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Using a temp table it runs in under 1 second, filling the temp table with the query used in the subselect takes 7 seconds. I rather don't use a temp table. No indexes on any table at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were my query I'd look at

1. simplifying the query to use intermediate table variables or temp tables,
2. simplifying the where clauses if possible, experimentally, just to see if that's related to the problem,
3. seeing if there's an index on [C_DS_DB_FI_SOK].D_7.

Sql Server is good at optimizing, but some things are just too complicated for it.

(After researching "Answers found in comment fields" I see that I perhaps should have posted as an answer instead of a comment.  I hope this isn't doing anything wrong.)

Comment: After using a temp table it's super fast. I did not know the use of temp tables was necessary in sql server for certain tasks.